# Find Firewall in use via Powershell

Tags: powershell, firewall

How can I use Powershell to find the name of the firewall that is enabled on a machine?

I don't want to know if the firewall is enabled or not, I just want to know **the name of it**, i.e. what you see in Security and Maintenance in Control Panel. Thanks!

Control Panel Security Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script runs for me on Windows 10 version 1809:

```
$computer   = '.'                                             # $env:COMPUTERNAME
$namespaces = "ROOT\SecurityCenter", "ROOT\SecurityCenter2"
$classname  = "FirewallProduct"
$ActiveFireWall = foreach ($namespace in $namespaces) {
    $aux = Get-WmiObject -Class $classname -Namespace $namespace -ComputerName $computer
    if ($aux) {
        $aux | Select-Object -Property [a-z]* -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, 
                 Scope, Path, Options, ClassPath, Properties, SystemProperties, 
                 Qualifiers, Site, Container
    }
}
if ( $ActiveFireWall ) { $ActiveFireWall.displayName }
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!